# Просмотр профиля пользователя

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Помогите пожалуйста реализовать такую вещь. У каждого пользователя есть свой профиль, в нем дата рождения,фото и т.п. Как можно сделать, чтоб другой пользователь мог смотреть эти страницы (профили) других пользователей? Например? есть список всех пользователей, человек нажал на одного из них и открылся профиль того, кого выбрал.

Comment: Получение в адресной строке id профиля, типа example.com/profile.php?id=123
а там уже загрузка нужных данных из БД.

Comment: [может быть именно то что вы искали](http://hashcode.ru/questions/55106/%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%B4)

Comment: А как именно получить id?как вывести?

Comment: вопрос из разряда "как дышать" - очень просто, берешь и дышишь :D

Comment: Пора бы придумать разделы FAQ для самых умных и многие вопросы поместить туда. очень часто идентичные вопросы задаются.

Comment: @Allan, странно, у вас что-то типа соц. сети, но вы не знаете, как получить параметр запроса. Взяли какие-то исходники?
Совет - учите спокойно язык, а не чисто по одним исходникам чего-либо.

Comment: Я считаю, что сначала обучиться азам нужно :))) Человек, знающий PHP не стал бы задавать таких вопросов.

Answer (score 1):

Получаем из URL данные GET запроса:
$id = $_GET['id'];

Заходим в phpMyAdmin, выполняем поиск, копируем SQL запрос, на место id вставляем $id. Читаем это: http://php.su/mysql/?functions